# Passing ArrayList elements between Forms? C#

Tags: c#

Form1:

```
public ArrayList listem = new ArrayList(20);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listem[0].toString());
}   // this is working
```

I added strings to listem from listem.txt file.

Using `MessageBox.Show(listem[0].toString())` on form1 is working.

Form2 :

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void sayfa_guncelle()
{      
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    MessageBox.Show(frm1.listem[0].toString().toString());      
}    

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sayfa_guncelle();
}   // this is not working
```

I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Where are you calling `listem.Add`?

Comment: actually values from a text file to my array list...

Comment: Please show them - are they getting called somewhere? Like in the constructor or the form `Load` event? You don't show enough code to answer the question, but presumably after you instantiate your form you need to call the method that adds items to the arraylist before you can call `ToString` on them.

Comment: As a side note, `ArrayList` is deprecated. Use `List<T>` instead. Read the contents of the blue box [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: i edited my codes

Comment: if you don't proof, your  `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` is creating and filling frm1.listitem, nobody can help you.

Comment: I added strings to listem from listem.txt file. - can you please post the code which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application.OpenForms Property to do it.

Code:

Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ArrayList listem = new ArrayList(5);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listem[0].ToString());
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listem.Add(1);
            listem.Add(2);
            listem.Add(3);
            listem.Add(4);
            listem.Add(5);
        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form =(Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            string a = form.listem[0].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(a);


        }
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// GlobalVars.cs
public class GlobalVars
{
    // member variables
    private static Lazy<GlobalVars> INSTANCE = null;
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();


    // constructor
    private GlobalVars()
    {

    }

    // get single instance of GlobalVars from here
    public static GlobalVars getInstance()
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
        {
            INSTANCE = new Lazy<GlobalVars>(() => new GlobalVars());
        }
        return INSTANCE.Value;
    }


    // properties
    public ArrayList MyList { get => list; set => list = value; }


    // add others public properties in here
    // ...
}


// Form1.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private GlobalVars globalVars;
    private Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // instance of GlobalVars 
        globalVars = GlobalVars.getInstance();

        // set capacity for 4 list
        globalVars.MyList.Capacity = 4;

        // add list1
        if (!globalVars.MyList.Contains("list1"))
        {
            globalVars.MyList.Add("list1");
        }

        // add list2
        if (!globalVars.MyList.Contains("list2"))
        {
            globalVars.MyList.Add("list2");
        }

        // show list1
        MessageBox.Show(globalVars.MyList[0].ToString());

        // show list2
        MessageBox.Show(globalVars.MyList[1].ToString());


        // show all list
        String items = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < globalVars.MyList.Count; i++)
        {
            items = items + globalVars.MyList[i].ToString() + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(items);
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // show form2
        if(form2 == null) {
            form2 = new Form2();
        }
        form2.Show();
    }


// Form2.cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    GlobalVars globalVars;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // instance of GlobalVars 
        globalVars = GlobalVars.getInstance();


        // add list3
        if (!globalVars.MyList.Contains("list3"))
        {
            globalVars.MyList.Add("list3");
        }

        // add list4
        if (!globalVars.MyList.Contains("list4"))
        {
            globalVars.MyList.Add("list4");
        }

        // show list3
        MessageBox.Show(globalVars.MyList[2].ToString());

        // show list4
        MessageBox.Show(globalVars.MyList[3].ToString());


        // show all list
        String items = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < globalVars.MyList.Count; i++)
        {
            items = items + globalVars.MyList[i].ToString() + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(items);
    }
}
```